# How to find the icon file linked to an executable?

Tags: x11, icons, cpp

I am building a window manager and I need to locate the icons related to a running executable for the taskbar. I found the Icon Specifications and was able to locate all the icons in `/usr/share/icons/theme_name` (I am on arch linux, if that matters). I also found the `.desktop` files  (which contain the icon path and executable path) in `/usr/share/applications`.

The issue is linking the `.desktop` files with running executables. I was thinking the name of the running window would match the name of the `.desktop` file; however, the name of the running window is more specific to the window itself. E.g. calling `XGetWindowProperty` on the terminal returns name as the directory the terminal is currently in, and visual studio code returns the file name, user name, and "Visual Studio Code."

Is there any way to link the two. As in know which `.desktop` file is used by which running window. Or even directly know which icon is supposed to be used by which running window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A running X11 application doesn’t reference an icon file, it makes its icon image data available in [the `_NET_WM_ICON` property](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html) attached to the application window. By decoding that you can find the image data to display:

> This is an array of possible icons for the client. This specification does not stipulate what size these icons should be, but individual desktop environments or toolkits may do so. The Window Manager MAY scale any of these icons to an appropriate size.
>
> This is an array of 32bit packed CARDINAL ARGB with high byte being A, low byte being B. The first two cardinals are width, height. Data is in rows, left to right and top to bottom.

Comment: I have accepted this as an answer, because this does answers the question. I have left my implementation in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Stephen Kitt pointed out the _NET_WM_ICON property. I eventually figured out how to get the image data from it.

The following is my implementation where `img_data` is the resulting ARGB raw image data. I use Imlib2 to display the image.

```
const Atom NET_WM_ICON = XInternAtom(DISPLAY, "_NET_WM_ICON", false);
const Atom CARDINAL = XInternAtom(DISPLAY, "CARDINAL", false);

Atom type_return;
int format_return;
unsigned long nitems_return;
unsigned long bytes_after_return;
unsigned char* data_return;

XGetWindowProperty(DISPLAY, window, NET_WM_ICON, 0, 1, false, CARDINAL, &type_return, &format_return, &nitems_return, &bytes_after_return, &data_return);
const int width = *(int*)data_return;
XFree(data_return);

XGetWindowProperty(DISPLAY, window, NET_WM_ICON, 1, 1, false, CARDINAL, &type_return, &format_return, &nitems_return, &bytes_after_return, &data_return);
const int height = *(int*)data_return;
XFree(data_return);

XGetWindowProperty(DISPLAY, window, NET_WM_ICON, 2, width * height, false, CARDINAL, &type_return, &format_return, &nitems_return, &bytes_after_return, &data_return);

uint32_t* img_data = new uint32_t[width * height];
const ulong* ul = (ulong*)data_return;

for(int i = 0; i < nitems_return; i++)
{
    img_data[i] = (uint32_t)ul[i];
}

XFree(data_return);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can call the following script like `./gjs-script "org.gnome.Calculator.desktop"` to get the icon:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gjs

const { Gio } = imports.gi;
let apps = Gio.AppInfo.get_all().find(a => a.get_id() == ARGV[0]);
print(apps.get_icon().to_string());
```